# Google hangout api - close / reopen apps from participants side

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

how can the participant of the hangout close and reopen an app , that developed  using "google hangout api" and with type of  ROOM_APP , there is no any close button"(x) for example " !!.  the only way is to open a text chat to run out of the app. 
also is there any opening button for the app to use ,  after closing it ?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the participant must active his/her google account to do what ever he/her want :) .